# AWS: Auto-create spot instances from specific AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to instruct `AWS` to:

- create `X` (number) spot instances from specific `AMI`? (I guess this is the easy part)
- create something periodic so that when these spot instances are terminated, create `X` new ones from the same `AMI`?

Comment: Sounds like this could solve your problem.  [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/asg-launch-spot-instances.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/asg-launch-spot-instances.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When launching Amazon EC2 spot instances, you must specify an AMI. Therefore, choose the desired AMI when launching the spot instances.

Your desire to keep a certain number of spot instances running sounds like an excellent use-case for an [Amazon EC2 Spot Fleet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet.html). A **Spot Fleet** allows you to specify the types of EC2 instances you would like to be available (instance type, AZ, price) and any instances terminated by Spot capacity can be **automatically replaced** with other spot instances of a different instance type, AZ, etc, that is not affected by the capacity issue that terminated the previous instances.